# Problem with magento 2.0.2 CE after upgrading to php7.0

Tags: magento2, php-7, mcrypt

I had a perfectly good and running magento 2.0.2 CE but after I updated the php version from php5.6 to php7.0  everything stopped working and i get the fallowing output in the var/report/errornumberfile:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:168:"Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH' in /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 397";i:1;s:3415:"#0 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(397): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Use of undefine...', '/var/www/html/m...', 397, Array)
#1 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(313): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->getCrypt('ee4e3ea10ae0cdd...', 0, false)
#2 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Backend/Encrypted.php(107): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->decrypt('PayPal')
#3 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/MetadataProcessor.php(86): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted->processValue('PayPal')
#4 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/Data.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataProcessor->process(Array)
#5 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Data->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\MetadataProcessor), Array)
#6 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#7 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#8 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/DataFactory.php(46): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#9 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopePool.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config\DataFactory->create(Array)
#10 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Config.php(41): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopePool->getScope('default', NULL)
#11 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Area/FrontNameResolver.php(82): Magento\Backend\App\Config->getValue('admin/url/use_c...')
#12 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/module-backend/Helper/Data.php(206): Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->getFrontName(false)
#13 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Request/PathInfoProcessor.php(46): Magento\Backend\Helper\Data->getAreaFrontName()
#14 /magento_server_dir/var/generation/Magento/Backend/App/Request/PathInfoProcessor/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '/index.login.ac...')
#15 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php(161): Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), '/index.login.ac...')
#16 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(194): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->setPathInfo()
#17 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php(204): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->getPathInfo()
#18 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(110): Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getFrontName()
#19 /magento_server_dir/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#20 /magento_server_dir/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#21 {main}";s:3:"url";s:19:"/index.login.action";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Does someone knows the solution to this problem ? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Have you installed the mcrypt extension for php7?

Comment: i figured that was the problem but i haven't found the correct way to install that extension for php7. can you help me with this ?

Comment: How did you installed php7 ? What OS are you running? Are you using php-mod or php-fpm? Anything else about your system that you could tell me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How did you installed php7 ? What OS are you running? Are you using php-mod or php-fpm?

If you are running ubuntu and you installed using PPA, then try this

Check if mcrypt module is there:

```
php -m | grep mcrypt
```

If not then install mcrypt:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt
```

Then enable the module:

```
phpenmod mcrypt
```

Then restart php.

Comment: that solved the problem. thank you. OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I had the same problem and many other modules were missing, so you can install them the same way as described above just change the module name

Comment: Do you have any idea why after I update to php 7.0 none of the commands for magento work in terminal ? Like all of the fallowing are not working : php bin/magento list, php7.0 bin/magento list, php7 bin/magento list. It gives output in console like:"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
bin/magento must be run as a CLI application" And that is it.... I really don't get it... when i try to install php7.0-cli it says "php7.0-cli is already the newest version." ... wtf

Comment: not really, I will check, but post this as a separate question as it seems as a different topic and there might be others that can provide an answer